# Perl array not saving all variables

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a Perl program that's parsing data from an external program and saving it to an array. However, some of the data isn't being saved and comes back blank when trying to retrieve it later.

Here's the code parsing the data, which comes through as `@packetData`:

```
if(@packetData[0] ne ""){
    if(!$detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"}) {
        my $rawSignal = average(@packetData[2]);
        my $distance  = 10**((27.55-(20*logten(2437))+abs($rawSignal))/20);
        my @newClient = ($rawSignal,   # Signal (dBm)
                       1,              # Count
                       @packetData[0], # Source MAC
                       time(),         # Last seen
                       $distance);     # Distance (m)
        $detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"} = [@newClient];
        $uniqueClient++;
        print "++ New probe request from @packetData[0] [$rawSignal dBm, $distance m]\n";
    } else {
        $detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"}[1]++;
        $detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"}[3] = time();
    }
}
```

The `print` statement shows the signal and distance fine, but trying to show it from the `detectedClient` array gives with the code below gives a blank space:

```
for $key2 ( keys %detectedClient) {
    #Signal, Count, MAC, Time
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($detectedClient{$key2}[3]);
    my $lastSeen = sprintf("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
    print STDOUT sprintf("!! %-20s %10s %-20s\n", $detectedClient{$key2}[2], $detectedClient{$key2}[1], $lastSeen, $detectedClient{$key2}[0], $detectedClient{$key2}[4]);
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Comment: I have both at the top of the script, but omitted them (along with the rest of the script) for clarity

Comment: @CyberJacob: If you have `use warnings` in place then you are ignoring the message `Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0]`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @CyberJacob Since it's hard to debug other people's code when you have to fill in missing pieces by guesswork, I would recommend creating a [mcve], including sample input data.

Comment: Re "*I have both at the top of the script,*", huh, the code you posted doesn't compile with them, and emits numerous warnings.

Comment: Tip: `$detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"} = [@newClient];` is a wasteful version of `$detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"} = \@newClient;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal and the distance aren't printed because your pattern (`"!! %-20s %10s %-20s\n"`) doesn't reference them (the 4th and 5th values). Fix:

```
printf("!! %-20s %5s %-20s %20s %20s\n",
    $detectedClient{$key2}[2],
    $detectedClient{$key2}[1],
    $lastSeen,
    $detectedClient{$key2}[0],
    $detectedClient{$key2}[4],
);
```

---

Tested using the following: (Had to change `for $key2` to `for my $key2` too)

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use List::Util qw( sum );

sub average { sum(@{ $_[0] })/@{ $_[0] } }

sub logten { log($_[0])/log(10) }

my @packetData = ("foo", undef, [ 4, 5 ]);

my %detectedClient;
my $uniqueClient;
if(@packetData[0] ne ""){
    if(!$detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"}) {
        my $rawSignal = average(@packetData[2]);
        my $distance  = 10**((27.55-(20*logten(2437))+abs($rawSignal))/20);
        my @newClient = ($rawSignal,   # Signal (dBm)
                       1,              # Count
                       @packetData[0], # Source MAC
                       time(),         # Last seen
                       $distance);     # Distance (m)
        $detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"} = [@newClient];
        $uniqueClient++;
        print "++ New probe request from @packetData[0] [$rawSignal dBm, $distance m]\n";
    } else {
        $detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"}[1]++;
        $detectedClient{"@packetData[0]"}[3] = time();
    }
}

for my $key2 ( keys %detectedClient) {
    #Signal, Count, MAC, Time
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($detectedClient{$key2}[3]);
    my $lastSeen = sprintf("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
    printf("!! %-20s %5s %-20s %20s %20s\n",
        $detectedClient{$key2}[2],
        $detectedClient{$key2}[1],
        $lastSeen, $detectedClient{$key2}[0],
        $detectedClient{$key2}[4],
    );
}
```

Output:

```
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 18.
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 19.
Scalar value @packetData[2] better written as $packetData[2] at a.pl line 20.
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 24.
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 27.
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 29.
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 31.
Scalar value @packetData[0] better written as $packetData[0] at a.pl line 32.
++ New probe request from foo [4.5 dBm, 0.0164302613184467 m]
!! foo                      1 2016/05/16 15:19:38                   4.5   0.0164302613184467
```

Next time, please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score -3):

The syntax for an entire array is `@array` but to access individual elements, it is (e.g.) `$array[0]`

Also, there is a better way to write the inner `if` in your context.

Third, you're using an array reference for `detectedClient`, so the syntax could be changed from `$detectedClient{$smac}[1]++` to `$detectedClient{$smac}->[1]++` that would be clearer as to intent. I've changed it in the code below, and you'll could also change it when printing as well.

Here's your code modified to reflect all that and shortened to use a scalar:

```
my $smac = $packetData[0];

if ($smac ne "") {
    if(! ref($detectedClient{$smac})) {
        my $rawSignal = average($packetData[2]);
        my $distance  = 10**((27.55-(20*logten(2437))+abs($rawSignal))/20);
        my @newClient = ($rawSignal,   # Signal (dBm)
                       1,              # Count
                       $smac,          # Source MAC
                       time(),         # Last seen
                       $distance);     # Distance (m)
        $detectedClient{$smac} = [@newClient];
        $uniqueClient++;
        print "++ New probe request from $smac [$rawSignal dBm, $distance m]\n";
    } else {
        my $ptr = $detectedClient{$smac};
        $ptr->[1]++;
        $ptr->[3] = time();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Applying the use of a scalar and a bit of reindent, the print code looks like:

```
for $key2 ( keys %detectedClient) {
    my $ptr = $detectedClient{$key2};

    #Signal, Count, MAC, Time
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
        localtime($ptr->[3]);
    my $lastSeen = sprintf("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
        $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);

    print STDOUT sprintf("!! %-20s %10s %-20s\n",
        $ptr->[2], $ptr->[1],
        $lastSeen, $ptr->[0], $ptr->[4]);
}
```

Now, it's a little easier to see [for me, at least ;-)] that the format is short by two fields [so the last two arguments won't be printed].

So, something like this instead:

```
printf("!! %-20s %10s %-20s %10s %10s\n",
```

Comment: `$foo{bar][1]` is exactly the same as `$foo{bar}->[1]`.  Arrows between brackets/braces are not required.  Please read: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule

Comment: @PaulL I had pushed an earlier version by mistake. Herein, they are required. Also, the syntax is clearer as to intent, IMO [and I've been writing perl for 20+ and have some 250,000 lines of it]

Comment: It's your answer that needs to change, in addition to the code.  You are claiming that OP made a syntactic error by omitting the arrows between the subscripts.  He did not.  That is not an error of any kind.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. (Also, adding arrows is contrary to idiom, and `$ptr` is a needlessly vague var name. Negating the `if` allows one to use `if( my $client = $detectedClient{$smac} ) { ...former else part... } else { ...former then part... }`

Comment: @ikegami "Adding arrows is contrary to idiom"? Are you serious? For a language whose mantra is "there's more than one way to do it"? If you put an array reference into a scalar you _must_ use `$whatever->[whatever]`. And, I updated the answer, so that it _does_ answer the question. Nobody else cleaned up things (i.e. I hope you're not going to defend using `@packetData[]` spelled out in _eight_ places, or equiv code in the print section). As to use of `ptr`, it was a _deliberate_ choice as a teaching tool to emphasize "pointer to" and using a scalar reference to an array--a new concept for OP

Comment: @ikegami You didn't actually suggest using `if (my $client = $detectedClient{$smac})` did you? Embedding an assignment op inside an `if` is considered bad code in just about any language, particularly C. It also makes it hard to debug if the rhs is less trivial. For the record, I do _not_ write _idiomatic_ perl because, IMO, it produces some of the hardest to read, cryptic code, I've seen in any language [and I know plenty of others]. I write a lot of perl [and I _am_ a fan], but perl has lost the battle for the future because of the slavish insistence of fanbois to make it look like AP/L

Comment: @Craig Estey, Yes, I'm serious. Even though there can be many ways of doing things, people do find certain approaches clearer than others. I don't know why you find that hard to believe??? // You're free to write code differently than most others, but don't pretend that makes it easier to read. Lack of uniformity is the biggest detraction to readability and maintainability. // Wow, so not only did you use a meaningless variable name, you were trying to corrupt someone into thinking Perl had pointers! Great teaching job! // Hell no. You're the one insisting on using all kinds of useless symbols

Comment: You listed three things the OP did "wrong", which were not actually wrong at all. One of them was merely ugly and warning-producing, but didn't affect the result at all.  The second was a mere stylistict choice.  The third was you incorrectly telling him he'd done something wrong that he hadn't, and your way was vastly uglier and unnecessary.

It wasn't until @ikegami posted his answer containing what was *actually* wrong with the asker's code that you modified your answer to include that information as well.