# How to rename multiple files in a folder with a specific format?

Tags: perl, rename

I have many files in a folder with the format '{galaxyID}-cutout-HSC-I-{#}-pdr2_wide.fits', where {galaxyID} and {#} are different numbers for each file.  Here are some examples:

```
2185-cutout-HSC-I-9330-pdr2_wide.fits
992-cutout-HSC-I-10106-pdr2_wide.fits
2186-cutout-HSC-I-9334-pdr2_wide.fits
```

I want to change the format of all files in this folder to match the following:

```
2185_HSC-I.fits
992_HSC-I.fits
2186_HSC-I.fits
```

namely, I want to take out "cutout", the second number, and "pdr2_wide" from each file name.  I would prefer to do this in either Perl or Python.  For my Perl script, so far I have the following:

```
rename [-n];
    my @parts=split /-/;
    my $this=$parts[0].$parts[1].$parts[2].$parts[3].$parts[4].$parts[5];
    $_ = $parts[0]."_".$parts[2]."_".$parts[3];
    *fits
```

which gives me the error message

```
Not enough arguments for rename at ./rename.sh line 3, near "];" Execution of ./rename.sh aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I included the `[-n]` because I want to make sure the changes are what I want before actually doing it; either way, this is in a duplicated directory just for safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `rename` you get on Ubuntu (it's not the one that's on my ArchLinux box), but there are other ones out there. But, you've presented it oddly. The brackets around `-n` shouldn't be there and the `;` ends the command.

The syntax, if you are using what I think you are, is this:

```
% rename -n -e PERL_EXPR file1 file2 ...
```

The Perl expression is the argument to the `-e` switch, and can be a simple substitution. Note that this expression is a string that you give to `-e`, so that probably needs to be quoted:

```
% rename -n -e 's/-\d+-pdr2_wide//' *.fits
rename(2185-cutout-HSC-I-9330-pdr2_wide.fits, 2185-cutout-HSC-I.fits)
```

And, instead of doing this in one step, I'd do it in two:

```
% rename -n -e 's/-cutout-/-/; s/-\d+-pdr2_wide//' *.fits
rename(2185-cutout-HSC-I-9330-pdr2_wide.fits, 2185-HSC-I.fits)
```

There are other patterns that might make sense. Instead of taking away parts, you can keep parts:

```
% rename -n -e 's/\A(\d+).*(HSC-I).*/$1-$2.fits/' *.fits
rename(2185-cutout-HSC-I-9330-pdr2_wide.fits, 2185-HSC-I.fits)
```

I'd be inclined to use named captures so the next poor slob knows what you are doing:

```
% rename -n -e 's/\A(?<galaxy>\d+).*(HSC-I).*/$+{galaxy}-$2.fits/' *.fits
rename(2185-cutout-HSC-I-9330-pdr2_wide.fits, 2185-HSC-I.fits)
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  I am still a bit confused as to how I would run this code in batch mode for hundreds of files in a directory, rather than one file at a time, or are these lines what I would put into the command line?

Comment: Those are the actual commands you'd use on the command line. The `*.fits` is every file that ends in that file extension.

Comment: thank you, this worked! i am a little bit confused, however, on the syntax still because i have files of different formats that i want to rename in the same manner.  for example, some files in a different directory have the form "7-psf-calexp-pdr2_wide-HSC-I-9608-7,2-205.41092-0.41487.fits" and i want to rename this to "7-HSC-I-psf.fits". I'm not sure how I would rearrange the commands to do this, but I've tried "rename -n -e 's/-/-\d+-calexp-/-\d+pdr2_wide; /-/-//' *.fits" but this didn't work.

Comment: It's the same command. You then need a pattern that fits these other files. I can't make sense of the command in the comment. If you have a new question, ask a completely new question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

From your description `{galaxyID}-cutout-HSC-I-{#}-pdr2_wide.fits`, I assume that `cutout-HSC-I` is fixed.

Here's a script that will do the rename. It takes a list of files on `stdin`. But, you could adapt to take the output of `readdir`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

sub master
{
    my($oldname);

    while ($oldname = <STDIN>) {
        chomp($oldname);

        # find the file extension/suffix
        my($ix) = rindex($oldname,".");
        next if ($ix < 0);

        # get the suffix
        my($suf) = substr($oldname,$ix);

        # only take filenames of the expected format
        next unless ($oldname =~ /^(\d+)-cutout-(HSC-I)/);

        # get the new name
        my($newname) = $1 . "_" . $2 . $suf;

        printf("OLDNAME: %s NEWNAME: %s\n",$oldname,$newname);

        # rename the file
        # change to "if (1)" to actually do it
        if (0) {
            rename($oldname,$newname) or
                die("unable to rename '$oldname' to '$newname' -- $!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

---

For your sample input file, here's the program output:

```
OLDNAME: 2185-cutout-HSC-I-9330-pdr2_wide.fits NEWNAME: 2185_HSC-I.fits
OLDNAME: 992-cutout-HSC-I-10106-pdr2_wide.fits NEWNAME: 992_HSC-I.fits
OLDNAME: 2186-cutout-HSC-I-9334-pdr2_wide.fits NEWNAME: 2186_HSC-I.fits
```

---

The above is how I usually do things but here's one with just a regex. It's fairly strict in what it accepts [for safety], but you can adapt as desired:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

sub master
{
    my($oldname);

    while ($oldname = <STDIN>) {
        chomp($oldname);

        # only take filenames of the expected format
        next unless ($oldname =~ /^(\d+)-cutout-(HSC-I)-\d+-pdr2_wide([.].+)$/);

        # get the new name
        my($newname) = $1 . "_" . $2 . $3;

        printf("OLDNAME: %s NEWNAME: %s\n",$oldname,$newname);

        # rename the file
        # change to "if (1)" to actually do it
        if (0) {
            rename($oldname,$newname) or
                die("unable to rename '$oldname' to '$newname' -- $!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you get `exit(0)` for free at the end of a Perl program that doesn't otherwise exit before then.

Comment: @briandfoy It's a signature for me. And, it's _explicit_ (i.e. we ensure the program ends there). With more complex programs, there might be some [inadvertant] file scope code later on that you _don't_ want executed. And, sometimes I do: `$code = master(...); exit($code);` instead [I've 500,000+ lines of `perl` in my personal repo]

Comment: One of the tricks in providing good answers is not distracting the people who are already confused with features that are irrelevant to the point where they are stuck. I think an explicit exit despite anything that happened isn't a good thing to show anyone. Also, passing `@ARGV` to a subroutine that ignores it in favor of standard input is odd. And, since you mentioned being strict for safety, remember that `\d` is defined by the locale, so you don't know what's in that character class until you run the program. But, none of that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Huh, four years ago in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260086/2766176 you said 250k lines. You've been busy lately. I was off [on other projects](https://www.amazon.com/brian-d-foy/e/B002MRC39U) though, so the measly 120k I counted in my currently checked out repos isn't as impressive.